# Why is rotation not applied instantly?

Tags: unity, rotation

I am working though the [Space Shoot tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter) and I have just applied tilt to the player object. One of the things that I have noticed is that the tilt is not applied instantly but instead the player object can be seen to rotate to the new rotation position. Why does the rotation appear to applied over time (1/2 second maybe) instead of instantly?

My expectation would be that when I set an attribute the value is changed instantly, not over time. I understand that instantly snapping to a position might not be very desirable, but I can't find anything in the [unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) that explains the behavior I am observing. My desire is to understand this behavior so that I can account for it and take advantage of it, so please provide a link to any supporting documentaion.

Sample code that exhibits this behavior.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour {
    void FixedUpdate(){
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, rigidbody.velocity.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: because rigidbody.velocity is smooth it goes from zero to value over a sligth amount of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `Debug.Log(moveHorizontal)`, and that sheds a lot of light on what's happening. If you're using a keyboard, what happens when you press `d`, is not that moveHorizontal snaps from 0.0f to 1.0f. It gradually increases. It goes from `0.0f`, to `0.1f`, then maybe `0.3f`, and so-forth, until it eventually becomes `1.0f`. The final value of it being fully pressed.

What this means, is that your **velocity** is gradually changing. Your rotation is based on your velocity, so that means that your rotation changes gradually, rather than instantly.

If you want it to snap to a rotation and velocity, rather than move gradually, try:

```
move = move > 0.0f ? 1.0f : (move < 0.0f ? -1.0f : 0.0f);
/* equivilant to:
 * if (move > 0.0f) move = 1.0f;
 * else if (move < 0.0f) move = -1.0f;
 */
```

To cite a piece of documentation: [The Unity input manager](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html), scroll down to the `Properties` and `Function` table. You can see in that table:

```
Negative Button     The button used to push the axis in the negative direction.
Positive Button     The button used to push the axis in the positive direction.
```

As stated there, pressing a key "pushes" that axis in a direction. It doesn't set an axis, it gradually changes it. This results in something similar to what it would be on a joystick. In order to put a joystick to the right, you have to push it all the way there. On the keyboard, they emulate that pushing action. Resulting in something consistent across input systems.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense from the perspective of gradual rotation... I was going to ask for some documentation and explanation of why the velocity would be gradually increased, but you edited your answer while I was typing to add documentation. That is awesome! Thanks.

Comment: When you determine how much the axis is pushed, first store the axis value in a variable called `axisInput`, then use this code to get the axis value: `axisInput > 0 ? 1 : 0`. This will equal to 0 if the key is released, and to 1 when the key is pressed.

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 There's a slight problem with that, axisInput goes from -1 to 1 (Not 0 to 1.) Because there's not one, but **2** buttons (negative, and positive.) So you need to test for the positive button `axisInput > 0 ? 1` and the negative button `: (axisInput < 0 ? -1 : 0)`

Comment: @WolfgangSkyler Yes, sorry... I forgot it was an axis. I thought of it as a key. :)